# How to get access to the mongo db in node using mongo client outside the call back

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have been looking at these examples:

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/

But am rather confused on how to access db outside the call back. MongoClient.connect doesn't seem to return anything and I've tried declaring a var outside the connect call and then having the call back modify it but that doesn't seem work either. What should I be doing instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the callback of connect, declare a global by simply not using the "var" keyword.

Note : As javascript is asynchronous, there is no guarrantee that callback is run before you use variables outside it.
Using a timeout usually works.

Example Node File:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test',connectCallback);
function connectCallback(err, db) {
  col = db.collection('persons');
  console.log('Connected to mongodb');
  }
setTimeout(function() {
col.save( {task:"Access db outside callback",result: "Success"}, (err, result) => {
        if (err) 
            return console.log(err)
        console.log(result)
        })
},1000)
```

Mongo Shell output:

[image]